# For $\varphi \in C_0^{\infty}$ it holds that $d\varphi (x,v) = D\varphi(x)\cdot v$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Given a test function $\varphi \in C_0^{\infty}$ we have that $d\varphi (x,v) = D\varphi(x)\cdot v$.

I read that one has to use the chain rule to prove that but I'm not sure how to incorporate it here?

These are the definitions:

$$df(x,v) := lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}$$
$$Df(x)=(D_1f(x),\dots,D_nf(x))$$ with $D_{i}f(x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(x)$ and $C_0^{\infty}$ is the space of all test functions.

Comment: What's $d\varphi (x,v) $?

Comment: How do you define $C_0^\infty$, $d\varphi (x,v)$, and $D\varphi(x)\cdot v$?

Comment: Just updated it @azif00

Comment: To use chain rule, note $df(x, v) =d/dt ( f \circ  \gamma) (t)$, where $\gamma (t) = x + tv$.

Comment: Then I get after applying the chain rule $v \cdot D \varphi (x+tv)$ right? So I still have $tv$ in the argument or did I do something wrong?

Comment: As @ArcticChar says, consider $\gamma \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ defined by $\gamma(t) = x+tv$, and note that $d\varphi(x,v) = (\varphi \circ \gamma)'(0)$. The chain rule says that $(\varphi \circ \gamma)'(0) = D\varphi(\gamma(0))D\gamma(0)$. Since $\gamma(0)=x$, I will left to you see that $D\gamma(0)$ is $v$ seen as a column vector.

Comment: So $v_{i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t} x_{i}$ but I dont see how it correpsonds to our original $v$.

Comment: @azif00 any idea?